# Sitecore Query for DropTree Field

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I want to assign `DropTree` field source,so user can only select the children of the current node in the field.
I tried with this:

```
query:./child::*
```

& this as well:

```
query:./*
```

both these returning the first child & not the all children.

What I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

Here the structure:

- Services

  - Service Category 1 (It has the DropTree to select child item)

    - Service Detail Item 1
    - Service Detail Item 2
  - Service Category 2 (It has the DropTree to select child item)

    - Service Detail Item 1
    - Service Detail Item 2

if I try `query:../*` it always return the children of first Service category.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `Droptree` field the `source` query only specifies the root of the tree. That's why you need to select the node itself, not the children of the current node. Use

```
query:./ancestor-or-self::*
```

It will allow to select any descendant of the current item.

Comment: Sorry,it's look like its always take the same root & not the current node as root